How to modify system sound volume precisely in ubuntu 24.04
I can change the system alert sounds volume in the Settings app in Ubuntu 24.04 as the pictures show.
Settings -> Sound:

Volume levels;

However it just has a slider bar but not the percentage value. I want to set it in percentage, but I do not know how to do that. I cannot find the corresponding item in dconf-editor, gsettings, wpctl and alsamixer.
